# Proving that $a^n+b^n+c^n=0 \implies abc=0$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show that if $a^n+b^n+c^n=0$ with $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $n\ge 3$, then $abc=0$.

By letting $a=a_1/a_2$ and so on I think I have shown it is sufficient to prove it for $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$, but not sure how to proceed.

Edit: Is there an elementary proof? I've not quite got through the proof of Fermat yet, being an undergraduate.

Comment: If $n$ is even, then the claim is obviously true. If $n$ is odd, then any counterexample $(a,b,c)$ to your claim will give rise to a counterexample $(a,b,-c)$ to Fermat's last theorem, and vice versa. Thus, using Fermat's last theorem, the result is straightforward, but of course Fermat's last theorem is highly non-trivial!

Comment: You can consider only $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$. If $a=a_1/a_2$ etc. multiply everything by $a_2b_2c_2$.

Comment: "I've not quite got through the proof of Fermat yet, being an undergraduate." I doubt a lot of us have :D

Comment: Hi @Juris, that would reduce to the case $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}$. It is quite possible that some or all of $a,b,c$ are negative so we can't quite reduce to the case $a,b,c\in \mathbb{N}$. Assuming we have the same definition of $\mathbb{N}$, the set of natural numbers. :)

Comment: @AmiteshDatta sorry, I corrected. $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$ is what the OP had so there is no need for that erroneous $a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}$ :)

Comment: You can easily check that this problem is equivalent to FLT, so we can think the proof of this problem is as much difficult as the proof of FLT.

Comment: Hi @Juris, no problem - it's not like $\mathbb{N}$ is well-defined anyway. After all these years, it's still unknown whether $0\in \mathbb{N}$. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $a,b,c$ is not $0$. Then if $n$ is even, $a^n,b^n,c^n$ is bigger than $0$. So there obviously is a contradiction.

And if $n$ is odd, it can be changed to $a^n+b^n=(-c)^n$. Then it takes same form as the [Fermat's last theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem).

So, statement $a\neq0$, $b\neq0$ and $c\neq0$ is false. From this we can know that $abc=0$.

Answer (score 3):

If $n$ is even then all the individual terms are greater than $0$ unless and until one
of them is zero.

If $n$ is odd then it becomes $a^n+b^n=(-c)^n$ and now by using Fermat's Last Theorem which recently got proved we know that $abc=0.$

Answer (score 2):

Case of even $n$ is elementary.

For odd: One of them has to be negative. Rearrange them so that positive are on one side and negatives on another.

Use [Fermat's last theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem) that states that solutions are possible of

$x^n=y^n+z^n$ , $n\geqslant 3 , x,y,z \in \Bbb Z^+$

I have a marvellous proof of it but this margin is too small to contain it.